# Better way to use model class helper methods

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Inside my model class I am using a method call IsAlreadyAssigned, as follow:-

```
public partial class DataCenter 
{
     public bool IsAlreadyAssigned()
     {
         return (TMSRacks.Any() ||  TMsRouters.Any() || Zones.Any());
     }
}
```

The main aim of this helper method is to hide the delete button on the view if the object have child records; as follow:-

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id= item.ID}) 
    @if (!item.IsAlreadyAssigned()) 
    { 
        <text>|</text> 
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete",
                         "Delete", "DataCenter",
                         new { id = item.ID },
                         new AjaxOptions
                         { 
                             Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete (" + item.Name + ")",
                             HttpMethod = "Post",
                             OnSuccess = "deletionconfirmation",
                             OnFailure = "deletionerror"
                         })

    }
</td>
```

But on my index view which shows 10 records at a time,I will hide or display the delete link accordingly ,so I have to include all the navigation properties, in my query  as follow:-

```
public IQueryable<DataCenter> AllFindDataCenters(string q, bool forautocomplete = false)
{
    return from datacenter in tms.DataCenters.Where(a=> (String.IsNullOrEmpty(q)) || ( a.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith(q.ToUpper())))
        .Include(a=>a.Zones)
        .Include(a=>a.TMsRouters)
        .Include(a=>a.TMSRacks)
        select datacenter;
}
```

Other wise each record on my index view might make at most three queries to the DB to check if there is any child records.
So I ended up including all the navigation properties as shown above, just to implement the requirement of hiding /displaying a delete link . so is there a better way to manage my logic, as I do not need to display any of the navigation properties data (tmsrouter,tmsfirewalls,zonea),  I just want to know if atleat one record exists or not ?
Thanks

Comment: any is the most efficient method as per me..

Comment: but in my case i have to pull all the navigation properties , to decide if Any() return true or false .. this is the problem. my problem is not with the Any(), it self..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of working directly with your business models in your view, return a *view* model and expose the information you need e.g.

```
public class DataCenterViewModel
{
    ...
    public bool HasZones { get; set; }
    public bool HasTmsRouters { get; set; }
    public bool HasTmsRacks { get; set; }

    public bool AlreadyAssigned { get { return HasZones || HasTmsRouters || HasTmsRacks; } }
}
```

Then in your query construct your view models. Also, just an FYI, it's best to work with a more generic construct like `IEnumerable<T>` when passing stuff to the view, `IQueryable<T>` suggests you want to further query the data source once at the view.

```
public IEnumerable<DataCenterViewModel> AllFindDataCenters(string q, bool forautocomplete = false)
{
    return tms.DataCenters.Where(...)
                          .Select(x => new DataCenterViewModel
                                       {
                                           ...
                                           HasZones = x.Zones.Any(),
                                           HasTmsRouters = x.TMSRouters.Any(),
                                           HasTmsRacks = x.TMSRacks.Any()
                                       })
                          .ToList();

}
```

Then finally in your view

```
<td>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id= item.ID}) 
@if (!item.AlreadyAssigned) 
{
    ...
}
</td>
```

Comment: ya i got ur point, but unfortunately , it will be difficult at this stage to do such a major change in my application. i might consider ur approach in further releases. but is there a way to improve my original code in any way ?

Comment: @johnG It's not really a major change you are simply swapping out `DataCenter` for `DataCenterViewModel`. What sort of restrictions do you have then? I can't really suggest a change unless I know what your limitations are.

Comment: limitation is time and resources. i mean we are on our last stages. and i did some tuning and this came out . so modifying this for our 15 controller class will not be easy to do . thanks

Comment: @johnG so are you open to a change say in the `DataCenter` class? To add some properties?